# Multiple instances of process for same apps

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, ram, ram-usage

I have recently seen a spike in my RAM usage and when I checked in System monitor, I see that there are a lot of instances of process for Google chrome and Visual studio code. I had only opened 1 window of each of them but still it shows a lot of instances and all of them add up to consume big amount of RAM. Can someone help why is this happening?

[image: Multiple chrome and code instances]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, each tab has one process, unless the tabs are from the same domain. This is why when a tab crashes, other tabs work without any issue.

So, if you have multiple tabs of different websites, you should see different processes being run.

And Chrome is known to be a resource hog. [Read more here.](https://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/)